# Исключить записи из вывода

Tags: mysql, pdo

100 записей. Как вывести из БД 5 последних записей, при этом не учитывая последние 20?

Т.е должны вывестись записи от 80 до 75.

Comment: Использовать `LIMIT`например для указания от какой записи и сколько вывести

Comment: Это понятно. Только как, если кол-во записей всё время меняется, а выводить нужно всегда 5 последних не учитывая последние 20.

Comment: Могу предложить каждый раз считать общее кол-во записей в таблице и отнимать от этого числа 25. Получать значение, с которого нужно выводить 5 записей.

Comment: Это вариант тоже известен. Может есть более удобнее варианты. Подожду...если вариантов не будет, то этот и оставлю.

Comment: *кол-во записей всё время меняется, а выводить нужно всегда 5 последних не учитывая последние 20* Сортировку смени! на обратную... и бери записи с 21-й по 25-ю вне зависимости от того, сколько их там всего. `LIMIT 20,5`

Comment: @Akina вот это и ответ надо.

Answer (score 0):

Таким кодом можно посчитать количество строк в БД:

```php
$q="SELECT count(*) FROM имя_базы";
$res=mysqli_query($mySQL, $q);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$total_rows=$row[0];
```

А таким запросом получить 5 записей без учета 20 последних

```php
$end =  $total_rows -  25; \\  Считаем, с какой строки будем брать
\\  SQL  запрос с лимитом
"SELECT * FROM имя_базы ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ".$end.",5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, пойдет и так:

```
SELECT * FROM имя_базы ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20, 25
```

https://ruhighload.com/post/Mysql+LIMIT